# Why did a moderator delete this question about a paradox?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, deleted-questions

[What story has someone step on a butterfly in the past and change the future, and what is that effect called?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148450/what-is-that-paradox-similar-to-the-grandfather-paradox-when-doing-time-travel)

I can see some reasons for it to be closed (as 'Too Broad', per @Mike's comment). But what was so awful about it that a moderator felt that it needed to be deleted?

[image]

Comment: Unless you are only interested in replies from those who can view deleted questions, perhaps you could quote the question here.

Comment: @Blackwood - i'm not sure if posting deleted questions' contents is permitted in Meta questions?

Comment: Fair enough. I would have thought that re-posting inoffensive material should be okay, but I suppose it's better to be safe than sorry. I believe the question merited being closed as too broad since it was a story id question and the only information provided was that it involved a fairly common trope in time travel stories. Once it was closed, what need was there to keep it?

Comment: Related: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/668/why-has-this-question-been-deleted?rq=1

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida - You appear to have left Exile and moved to Florida...

Comment: @Valorum - it's a US thing. Florida is stereotypically associated with retirement here.

Comment: @Blackwood - i think it should be OK, but given certain past experiences, both experienced and observed, i'd rather be safe than sorry

Comment: In the absence of a comment from either Mod involved, perhaps you might want to ask a follow-up question; "***Why was this question reopened?***".

Comment: @Valorum - as long as it's reopened by the community (or isn't), I'm fine with that. I am on the fence on whether it should be opened or closed, my issue was the binding unilateral seemingly without an explanation delete.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida - I think the problem here is that it's not the first time (in recent memory) that a question has been closed without comment by moderator, something that's strongly advocated by the vaunted "Theory of Moderation". In this case *another* moderator has reversed their decision and reopened it, **again without any comment to explain their decision-making**.

Comment: @Valorum - reopening without a comment is less damaging than closing (although I agree, with comment is always better)

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida - And now it's been mod-reopened as well. This Q is the train wreck that won't end.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida so are YOU that infamous "Florida Man" I keep hearing about?!?!

Comment: @corsiKa - I must admit to having no clue as to what you're referring to. But since Florida for me is merely symbolic and not literal, presumably, no.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida it is becoming trendy to take headlines of the crazy things Floridians do (because they tend, for whatever reason, to be crazier than other states) specifically prefacing the deed with Florida Man - more at https://www.reddit.com/r/FloridaMan/

Comment: @corsiKa - ah no. I do my **own** crazy things, thankyouverymuch :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Update #2

The question has now been *mod-hammered* open by moderator Thaddeus Howze.

### Update #1

The question, having initially been deleted by moderator [Thaddeus Howze](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2765/thaddeus-howze), has now been undeleted by another moderator, [Kevin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3267/kevin).

**As yet there has been no explanation from either mod to justify the initial deletion, nor the decision to undelete.**

---

### This question should not have been deleted.

A brief look at the [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/148450/timeline) and [edit history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/148450/revisions) would suggest that the OP, not having read the tour (I'm *scowling* at you, OP) posted a meandering question that was actually in three parts. Two of these questions were story identification questions, the third was a more general "*What is this kind of paradox called?*" question. It was rightly closed as 'Too Broad' because it doesn't have a single coherent question.

The OP then made an edit to remove ***one*** of the story-ident elements leaving ***two*** questions, one about paradoxes in fiction, the other a story-ident question. For some reason, the question then began attracting reopen votes.

At this point a moderator deleted the question. I'm unsure why they took this action but since the question is neither unsalvageable (a very quick edit would remove one of the questions), nor contains inappropriate language there really isn't a good reason to delete an already closed question, one that the OP is in the process of fixing.

Comment: @RandalThor - Cheers for the edit. Don't drink and drive, kids.

Comment: A note on the reopening (not the undeletion): Thaddeus was one of **four** reopen-voters - fewer than would be needed without mod intervention, but he wasn't acting unilaterally either.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - And while that's true, the fact that he deleted it, didn't undelete it, **then mod-opened** it is just a truly bizarre chain of events.

Answer (score 0):

Talking as the guilty party in the question, I had seen/read two or more stories which seemed to have a similar trope. Now I was handicapped because I knew what the trope is about but didn't know what it is called. To add to that, as I had read/seen those stories/movies far apart I wasn't able to fully remember the details.

So now, I'm in a fix how to describe the trope as well as how to figure about those stories as for me they both went hand-to-hand. I didn't mind the fact that I got hammered but was much more excited and thrilled as I learnt two-three similar tropes which are used in science fiction. For e.g. the "timeline split plus butterfly effect" and the other points raised by Lserni were really cool.

As far as the tour is concerned, I took it twice and the ones it is at the fence are about -

a. List of works with a particular plot element

b. Or any other question with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

Now as a questionaire, sometimes it makes it pretty difficult to know which questions are broad and which aren't. One of the things that the site tour doesn't tell or cherish is "Assume good faith" . If this was part of the tour then it wouldn't have caused as much heartburn as it did to both sides.

Comment: At the time you hadn't read the tour; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/105/informed?userid=33101

Comment: For the record, this meta question isn't actually about your question (except tangentially), it's about why site moderators Thaddeus Howze and Kevin took the actions they took.

Comment: As to whether your ]question/s were appropriate, the answer is yes, yes, yes and no. Yes to "***What story is this(1)?***", Yes to "***What story is this(2)?***", yes to "***What is the name of this trope?***" and no to "***What other stories include this trope?***"

Answer (score 0):

I was one of the people who originally voted to close the question as "too broad". I did so because it was asking for the name of a movie, and the only identifying information provided was that it featured a rather common sci fi trope. In other words it seemed to me to be too broad.

Comment: Sorry, the question was about binding moderator action of deletion specifically, not about community VTC (which is reasonably obvious as to "why")

Comment: To echo DVK, I think we're in broad agreement that it should have been *closed*, the question is why a moderator chose to *delete* it, especially after they'd used their mod powers to reopen it shortly before.